# Check whether a "Recurring Date" lies between two DateTime instances

Tags: c#, datetime

We have a class called `ABDate` which contains among other things a `Month`, a `nullable Year` and a `Day`. When creating an instance of `ABDate` if the year is given as `null`, the date is considered recurring. There is an `IsRecurring` property as well.

Now we have a `IList<ABDate>`, and we are given a start and an end `DateTime`. How do we check to see whether any `ABDate` in the list lies in the start and end interval.

Comment: Will this system have to deal with timezones, daylight-saving time, ...?

Comment: We are dealing with DST, no timezones, thanks for asking

Comment: @Stefan : Yes, i have tried your code, but the test cases are still running, and we are verifying all cases, i will definitely comment on your answer, if it succeeds or fails, either way. Also your code helps to avoid if/else type conditions. I agree the ternary is there but still :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the non-recurring case the solution is obvious. Given a collection `abDates` and `start` and `end` instances:

```
var anyInBetween = abDates
    .Select(ab => new DateTime(ab.Year.Value, ab.Month, ab.Day))
    .Any(d => d >= start && d <= end);
```

For the recurring case, we can observe that since no month has more than 31 days, a function such as `f(month, day) = month * 100 + day` will project each distinct (month, day) tuple into a unique integer. Comparing two such integers allows us to determine which of the source tuples represents a day earlier in the year:

```
// Note: m * 100 is "random". Multiplying by any factor > 31 will work as well.
Func<int, int, int> customTotalOrder = (m, d) => m * 100 + d;
var startIndex = customTotalOrder(start.Month, start.Day);
var endIndex = customTotalOrder(end.Month, end.Day);
var spanningYears = end.Year - start.Year;
var anyInBetween = false;

switch (spanningYears)
{
    default:
    case 2:
        // start => end contains at least one whole year, so obviously...
        anyInBetween = abDates.Any();
    case 1:
        var projection = abDates.Select(ab => customTotalOrder(ab.Month, ab.Day));
        anyInBetween = startIndex < endIndex
            ? projection.Any(i => i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex)
            : projection.Any(i => i >= startIndex || i <= endIndex);
    case 0:
        anyInBetween = abDates
            .Select(ab => customTotalOrder(ab.Month, ab.Day))
            .Any(i => i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex);
}
```

Comment: I like that you choose 100 for your example to point out that its not important which lenght you pretend for a month as long as its >= 31. it will result in an unique integer. for a year you can do the same as long as 11 * month_value (100 in you case) + 31 <= year_value. Beside that i think you could solve this easier but with the same assumption than you did in your code.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I get the code and its really nice, but could you please explain the code flow a bit : when `StartDate = 31-Jan-2014` and `EndDate = 28-Feb-2015` and the date to check is `22-April`. I might have it wrong but i think `case 1:` might return false with this.

Comment: @Abhi: I didn't run the code, but by reading it again it looks to me that it will work correctly. Basically the conditional tests if the span is greater than a year; if it is, it relaxes the requirement for the projected integers accordingly.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in the example i gave, the EndDate = 28-Jan-2015. It returns "false" when StartDate = 31-Jan-2014 and EndDate = 28-Jan-2015 and the date to check is 22-April.

Comment: @Abhi: Oops. My bad now -- I had incorrectly swapped the `&&` and `||` operators. Edited the answer, what about now?

Comment: Yep, Working good now, Thanks a bunch. The idea was very nice, to multiply, would be optimizing further based on our needs. Marking as answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (ABDate a in AbDateList)
  {

    for ( in checkYear = startDate.Year ;checkYear <= EndDate.Year; checkYear ++)
    {
         if ((new DateTime(checkYear ,a.Month,a.Day) >= startDate) && (new DateTime(checkYear ,a.Month,a.Day) <= endDate))
           {
              // I AM IN BETWEEN
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would probably want something like `new datetime(a.Year.GetValueOrDefault(startDate.Year),a.month,a.Day)` to handle the non recurring type

Comment: How does this handle the recurring case?

Comment: @Jon not sure if that question was directed to me? if a.Year is defined then that is used to construct the new DateTime otherwise it will use the comparing startDate.Year. the other logic I assumed correct though I can see issues where the start/end span a year

Comment: @DavidEwen: No, was directed to Traci.

Comment: I think Traci's code might fail with the following input: `StartDate = 27-Jan-2014` and `EndDate = 2-Feb-2016` and the date to check is = `22 Jan 2015`.